# C# 文字列を反転させて描画する方法

Tags: c#, winforms

お世話になります。

Graphicsに描画するときに、文字列を反転して描画する
メソッドなどのようなものはありますでしょうか。

『回転』ではなく、上下や左右の『反転』です。

極力軽い手段を探しています。反転した文字列をもとにGraphicsに
点で打って描画していくとかはNGです。
簡単な方法がないならないという回答でも構いません。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

描画方法としてはWPF相互運用で`TextEffect`を適用した`TextBlock`を描画するのが柔軟で描画品質も期待できるかと思います。もしくは他のWPFタイポグラフィ低レベルAPIを使用する手もあります。
ですが「簡単な方法」ではないですね。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。方法としてはあるとは思うのですが、それを『簡単に』というので引っかかってしまいますね。フォントの中には、＠マークがついている縦書き用のものがありますが、あんな感じでもいいかとはお思っていましたが、なかなか簡単にはいかないようです。

Answer (score 2):

[Graphics.ScaleTransform()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/zhc2xxtx(v=vs.110).aspx)でY方向に-1倍スケールすれば上下反転しませんか？ 同様にX方向に-1倍で左右反転。
`Graphics`でなく`Image`クラスであれば[Image.RotateFlip()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip(v=vs.110).aspx)が用意されています。 `RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY`や`RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX`が上下・左右反転です。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。ScaleTransform()は、全体的に反転されませんか？まだよく確認していないのですが、文字列単位ではなく、矩形単位の様な気もします。文字を描画するという方法で反転させたいのです。それも、通常にdrawStringと混合して、反転文字もできればと思ったのですが…。あと、Imageは既にやったことがあるので問題ないのですが、今回は『文字列の反転』なんです。個人的な希望では、drawStringの引数内にRotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipYやRotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipXなんかを渡せればいいと思うのですが、そういったのはないようですね。

Comment: @たたぱた さん、テンポラリの`Bitmap`を作成し、そこに文字を描画後に上下・左右反転を行い、出来上がった`Bitmap`を`Graphics.DrawImage()`を使って元の`Graphics`に描画されてはどうですか？

Comment: うーん…、結果的にはできると思いますが、一度Imageにしなければならないのが負担になっていますね。『文字列を加工して描画する』というよりは、『反転した文字列を描画する』…といった感じにしたいです。